# java pattern comparison with boolean

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

i got a problem here with my code, my task is to compare patterns with chars. somehow it returns true instead of false here. 
thanks for the help.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    char[] chars = {'a','b','c','d','e','f'};
    char[] patterns = {'x','y','z'};
    System.out.println(containsPattern(chars,patterns));}

public static boolean containsPattern(char[] chars, char[] patterns){

                for (int a=0; a<chars.length; a++){
                    if (chars[a]==patterns[a] || chars !=null &&
                            patterns.equals(chars));
                    return true;
                }
                return false;

     }
```

Comment: you have a semicolon at the end of `if()`

Comment: Also, you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you remove the `;`.

Comment: And the condition `chars !=null && patterns.equals(chars)` should be moved outside the loop. (And obviously the `equals` should be swapped.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semicolon. You have a semicolon after your if, so that is counted as the expression to do if the statement is true. Because you don't have brackets, only one expression is in the if's body. The "return true" will be done always.

Also, .equals doesn't work here, it doesn't compare the contents of the two array but only the memory address. It'd only return true if you'd say somewhere either `chars = patterns;` or `patterns = chars;`

And also, now you're just checking individual characters: you need to check three (length of pattern) consecutive chars to make sure the pattern is correct. I'm assuming you'd only want to return true when there's xyz n you chars, for example {a, b, x, y, z, c).
So, you need to do something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
    boolean matches = true;
    for(int j = 0; j < pattern.length; j++){
        if((i+j) >= chars.length || chars[i+j] != pattern[j]){
            matches = false;
            return;
        }
    }
    if(matches)
        return true;
}
return false;
```